# Sequelize mysql query where attribute is null

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have an address and I want to see if it's in the db already, if not, create a new one. I know I can use `findOrCreate()` here, but let's make it easy and just check why I can't even find the existing address.

```
  var address = {
    name: req.body.name,
    address1: req.body.address1,
    address2: req.body.address2,
    zip: req.body.zip,
    city: req.body.city,
    country: req.body.country,
    user_id: req.body.user_id
  };

  Address.find({where: address}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
  }).catch(function(err){
    console.error(err);
  });
```

The generated query asks for `... AND user_id = NULL`which is wrong. It should ask `... AND user_id IS NULL`. How can I let sequelize do it right for me? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just use the JavaScript null primitive.

```
var address = {
    name: req.body.name,
    address1: req.body.address1,
    address2: req.body.address2,
    zip: req.body.zip,
    city: req.body.city,
    country: req.body.country,
    user_id: req.body.user_id || null
};
```

This will generate the query

```
... user_id IS NULL
```

Additional information

```
model.findAll( { where: { some_column : undefined } } );
```

will generate

```
... WHERE `some_column` = NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will test this soon.

Comment: upvoted. btw you can also use `null` directly: `model.findAll( { where: { some_column : null } } );`

Comment: Must use "null"